# how to find out what are the other users connected to this server?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, users

I want to change the installation of a program, but it says that there are other users connected to this server, how can I find out who they are?

[image]

One way, as described by [root](https://superuser.com/users/254473/root) in the comments below, is to use the task manager.

that's great, but still it would be lovely to have a `powershell` solution.

[image]

Comment: An easy way is from the task manager. Click the Users tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works in CMD and PowerShell

```
query session /server:remotehostname
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-session

In older versions of Windows you can also use

```
qwinsta
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/qwinsta

Comment: There exists also `quser.exe`.